# Is this set a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

The collection of $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3)^T$ which can be expressed as a linear combination of $u = (2,0,-\frac{1}{2})^T$ and $v = (-3,-5,-7)^T$.

I rewrote this as $c_1(2,0,-\frac{1}{2})^T$ + $c_2(-3,-5,-7)^T$ = $(x_1,x_2,x_3)^T$

Putting them together, I found the reduced row echelon form to be
$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right)$.

I feel I should use this to say it is not a subspace, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are trying to use row-reduction.

To show the set:

$S = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3)^t \in \Bbb R^3: (x_1,x_2,x_3)^t = c_1(2,0,\frac{1}{2})^t + c_2(-3,-5,-7)^t, c_1,c_2 \in \Bbb R\}$

is a subspace, we need to show $3$ things:

$1$. $(0,0,0)^t \in S$.

$2$. If $(x_1,x_2,x_3)^t$ and $(y_1,y_2,y_3)^t$ are in $S$, then so is $(x_1,x_2,x_3)^t + (y_1,y_2,y_3)^t$.

$3$. If $c$ is any real number, and $(x_1,x_2,x_3)^t \in S$, then so is $c(x_1,x_2,x_3)^t$.

I feel generous today, so I shall grant you a boon:

If $(x_1,x_2,x_3)^t = c_1(2,0,\frac{1}{2})^t + c_2(-3,-5,-7)^t$ and

$(y_1,y_2,y_3)^t = d_1(2,0,\frac{1}{2})^t + d_2(-3,-5,-7)^t$

then:

$(x_1,x_2,x_3)^t + (y_1,y_2,y_3)^t = c_1(2,0,\frac{1}{2})^t + c_2(-3,-5,-7)^t + d_1(2,0,\frac{1}{2})^t + d_2(-3,-5,-7)^t$

$= (c_1+d_1)(2,0,\frac{1}{2})^t + (c_2+d_2)(-3,-5,-7)^t$, which is in $S$.